# Modify array of objects in Redux depeding on condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, lodash

In my Redux app I have an array of objects that represents list of days & hours of opened shop that looks like this:

```
[{day: 'Monday', from:'10', to:'18'}, {day: 'Tusday', from: '8', to:'16'}, {...}]
```

I have created a component that contains a list of days in a week. When clicking on one of a days a dispatch is done with payload thats represents a day:

```
{day: 'Monday', from:'10', to:'18'}
```

I start on an empty array, I push one dayObject to the array. When I am pushing the same object again it means I want to remove it (uncheck it on the React component).

When I change opening hour in one dayObject, I am pushing it again, with changed opening hour, so I want to remove old object and push the new one into array, with new hour.

```
  if(_.some(days,
    {
      day: action.payload.day
    }
  )) {
    // replace current object, how ?

  } 

  if(_.some(days,
    {
      day: action.payload.day,
      from: action.payload.from,
      to: action.payload.to
    }
  )) {
    // duplicate, uncheck on UI so remove it
    _.remove(days {day: action.payload.day})
  } else {
    days.push(action.payload)
  }
```

So, it looks like my problems lays in detecting if the object is a duplicate or it is a modified version of some dayObject, so I should replace it. Any help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you could dispatch an action in the format `{type: 'ACTION_TYPE', ...}`. This grants you the power to specify the action type so as to instruct your reducer how to work with the payload. I would imagine actions like `{type: 'REMOVE_DAY', day: {}}` and `{type: 'UPDATE_HOUR', day: {}}`.

Another important thing is to understand your model and your data structure. For example, will it be better to use an object with id instead of plain array? This way you can refer to your days using id instead of passing entire object around.

```
// Example reducer
const store = (state, action)=> {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_DAY':
      return [...state, action.payload];
    case 'REMOVE_DAY':
      return state.filter((date)=>(date.day !== action.payload.day));
    case 'UPDATE_DAY':
      return state.map((date)=>{
        if (date.day === action.payload.day) {
          return {...date, ...action.payload};
        }
        return date;
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

// Example action creator
const updateDay = (payload)=>{
  return {
    type: 'UPDATE_DAY',
    payload
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer. So it means I have to dispatch correct action inside my component. I was trying to have 1 action called MANAGE_DAYS and inside 3 if statments that would handle data, but I cannot make it work, so I will try to use your aproach.